# Error: Can't find common super class of 

Tags: java, optimization, obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to process with Proguard a MS Windows desktop application (Java 6 SE using the SWT lib provided by Eclipse). And I get the following critical error:

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class = [org/eclipse/swt/widgets/DateTime]
Method = [<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V]
Exception = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/StringBuffer] and [org/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/TCHAR])
Error: Can't find common super class of [java/lang/StringBuffer] and [org/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/TCHAR]
----------------------------
```

When I tried to Google the error, it came out only on two spots on the entire web, that astonished me greatly.
I am newbie using Proguard and Java code optimization tools at all.
Any thoughts and suggestions how to fix this, will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Above error is now fixed,** with the using of "-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses"

**--final update:**

I still get another error now.
The whole output is now the folowing:

```
D:\eclipse_projs\java_obfuscate\gci>gci.bat
ProGuard, version 4.4
Reading program jar [D:\eclipse_projs\java_obfuscate\gci\gci.jar]
Reading library jar [D:\jre1.6.0_07\lib\rt.jar]
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
  Class       = [org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Synchronizer]
  Method      = [runAsyncMessages(Z)Z]
  Instruction = [60] aload_1 v1
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue])
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Synchronizer]
  Method      = [runAsyncMessages(Z)Z]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue])
 Error: Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue]

D:\eclipse_projs\java_obfuscate\gci>
```

This is a problem that i cannot understand for certain :( any help will be much appreciated.

The options I use are the following:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-optimizationpasses 3
-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-dontnote
```

Comment: add -verbose to the command line if you haven't to get a full stack trace.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding the option `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses` to your command line.

From the [Proguard Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/limitations.html):

> ### Limitations
>
> For efficiency,
>   ProGuard always ignores any private or
>   package visible library classes while
>   reading library jars. If any of them
>   are extended by public library
>   classes, and then extended again by
>   input classes, ProGuard will complain
>   it can't find them. In that case,
>   you'll have to use the
>   `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses`
>   option, and maybe even the
>   `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers` option. The graphical user interface
>   has checkboxes for these settings.

Comment: yes, I did it, and those error has now been resolved.
Unfortunately, other errors are now rising:

I'm gonna add them up in my post above, as an update

Comment: yes thank you JRL, I'm trying the command line verison to get to work, coz it will be more convinient for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but did not try specifying the `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses` or any other option to get fixed. My problem was occurring on `java.lang.StringBuffer` class, which was very weird. `StringBuffer` class was being used all over the project and the error did not occur anywhere else.

To fix, all I did was to move the scope of `StringBuffer`.

OLD Code - with error:

```
function(){
   if(condition){
       StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
       //additional code
   }else if(condition){
       StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
       //additional code
   }
}
```

NEW Code - without problem.

```
function(){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

       if(condition){

           //additional code
       }else if(condition){

           //additional code
       }
    }
```

I have a feeling this has to do something with ProGuard and how it parses the code.

Comment: Did you ever find any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with an application depending on various other projects. I tried the listed solutions, but none of them help. Based on tests, the shrinking and preverify steps were correctly running, the optimization threw the error:

```
> java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [java/io/File] (with 2 known super classes) and [org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/gui/TreeViewer] (with 1 known super classes)
```

I tried keeping (-keep options) both classes without any success.
Based on other threads I found the minimal solution is to disable variable optimization:

```
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
```

This lets me compile successfully, but has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `-dontnote` option. You may have duplicate definitions that you aren't receiving warnings for, or maybe you're ignoring the warnings.

Comment: LOL :D
I am actually ignoring the warnings, how bad can this be ?

Now I will try to add warnings in -keepclassmembers, i'll write back my progress.

Comment: no actually I have NO warnings now currently. I had Only notes, and when I put -dontnote, I still get an error, that for me is impossible to comprehend. I did paste all the output in my original question as --final update, see above.