# Strange java.lang.VerifyError - VFY: 'this' arg 'Ljava/lang/String;' not instance of '(my-class-name)

Tags: java, android, verifyerror

I ran into a `java.lang.VerifyError` working on an Android application.

I Googled and came across various verify errors but could not find a solid reason for this to happen.

This is the stack trace.

I am using Android SDK Tools 22.3 and the application is running on Android 2.2

```
W/dalvikvm( 2327): VFY: 'this' arg 'Ljava/lang/String;' not instance of 'Lcom/mypackage/BPM/DATA_Manager_BPM;'
W/dalvikvm( 2327): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x74 at 0x085d
W/dalvikvm( 2327): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mypackage/DEALER/DEALER_FailedOperationManager$TransactionAsyncTask;.doInBackground ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
W/dalvikvm( 2327): Verifier rejected class Lcom/mypackage/DEALER/DEALER_FailedOperationManager$TransactionAsyncTask;
D/AndroidRuntime( 2327): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2327): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e8)
```

Does anyone know what "rejecting opcode 0x74" means of what this "**not instance of**" error means? Or any clue as to where to look ?

**UPDATE**

The signature of the TransactionAsyncTask is as follows.

```
class TransactionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Integer>
```

and I invoke it simply using `new TransactionAsyncTask().execute();`

The signature of `doInBackground` is

`protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params)`

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how that question would help this case. It's a NullPointerException

Comment: @laalto: I am afraid I cannot do that for two reasons. 1. I am not allowed to. 2. It's a long method (About 450 lines). I understand you would have a better chance to identify the issue if you had access to the code, but is there anything suspicious that I can take a look ? Thanks!

Comment: I'll answer what I can based on the information available then. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `doInBackground()`, there's a virtual method invocation (opcode 0x74, invoke-virtual with registers) called with a `String` as `this` pointer where `com.mypackage.BPM.DATA_Manager_BPM` is expected.

There are [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980047/proguard-error-with-method-signatures) that suggest there might be a ProGuard bug involved.

Comment: the error refers to the 'this' argument meaning that it is not an instance of the class that declared the method

Comment: @drorb: Can you please explain it further ?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray The first argument to [invoke-virtual/range](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html) is the "this" instance (the object whose method or constructor is being called). The verifier checks that it is an instance of the class that declared the method. In your case it expects com.mypackage.BPM.DATA_Manager_BPM but finds a String. You can take a look at the [verifier code](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/dalvik/source/b7fdbab46f67253caa15f2cc9d37be295239e075:vm/analysis/CodeVerify.c) for more info.