# ProGuard: StringBuffer

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

Trying to obfuscate my code with ProGuard.

These are my config

```
> -injars xxxx
> -outjars yyyyy
> 
> -libraryjars 'xxx\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar'
> -libraryjars 'xxx\ProvaProGuard\lib'
> -libraryjars 'xxx\Java\jre7\lib\jce.jar'
> 
> -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
> -dontshrink
> -dontoptimize
> 
> 
> -keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class controller.* {
>     <fields>;
>     <methods>; }
> 
> # Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
> # methods.
> -keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
>     public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }
> 
> # Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
> # enumeration classes.
> -keepclassmembers enum  * {
>     public static **[] values();
>     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }
> 
> # Also keep - Serialization code. Keep all fields and methods that are used for
> # serialization.
> -keepclassmembers class * extends java.io.Serializable {
>     static final long serialVersionUID;
>     static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
>     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
>     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
>     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
>     java.lang.Object readResolve(); }
> 
> # Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
> -keep class * extends java.sql.Driver
> 
> # Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
> # along with the special 'createUI' method.
> -keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
>     public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent); }
```

So. When I run, no problems occured.
But, if I open my .jar, I can find just a Class, inside package controller, it's just full of comments (I think stack) and a   /* Error */ headline.

I'm SO MUCH sure that problem is about StringBuffer.
I use String Buffer for create a message for mails.

I had same problem in another class and to resolve I've changed scope of my variables. (Code Below)

From this:

```
private static String sendMail() {
    try { 
        StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer footer = new StringBuffer();
       //CODE WHERE I USE header and footer
         return "Mail Disabilitata.";
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return MyUtils.stackTrace(t);
    }
}
```

to this

```
private static String sendMail() {
    StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer footer = new StringBuffer();
    try { 
        //CODE WHERE I USE header and footer
         return "Mail Disabilitata.";
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return MyUtils.stackTrace(t);
    }
}
```

Because [This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414220/2258585)

And for my first class, this work-around worked.

In my second class, (Controller, that one that I don't try to obfuscate, as you can see in my proguard config) it doesn't.

I'm pretty sure it's about StringBuffer.

Or at least (and I hope it's not) for multiple String that change over and over in just one method

Comment: I dont get your code. Why do you create local variables when they are unused? You create them to be thrown away. Whats the point of that in the first place?

Comment: Edit, with more details, but I gave that example because I used a work-around to make everything work. But I still have problem in my second class